# how to show two mysql tables values at one while loop using php

Tags: php, html

I have created two tables, table1 and table2
table1 includes (id, codes and titles).
table2 includes id, table1_id, column1, column2, column3
I want Insert value on table1(codes , titles)
and show in table using PHP
and insert table2(column1, column2, column3) and show it
under table1 values.
This my codes

```
<?php   
include('config.php');
$ret=" SELECT * from table1
";
$stmt= $mysqli->prepare($ret);
//$stmt->bind_param('i',$aid);
$stmt->execute() ;//ok
$res=$stmt->get_result();
$cnt=1;
while($row=$res->fetch_object())
{
?>

 <div class="card shadow">
 <div class="card-header py-0">
 <table class="table">
 <tr >
 <td style="border: none"><?php echo $row->codes; ?></td>
 <td style="border: none"><?php echo $row->titles; ?></td>
 <td style="border: none">edit</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
<div class="card-body">
                       
<div class="table-responsive table mt-2" id="dataTable" role="grid" aria- 
describedby="dataTable_info">
<table class="table my-0" id="dataTable">
<thead>
                              
<tr>
<th>column 1</th>
<th>column 2</th>
<th> column 3 </th>
                                       

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
                                <?php  



$ret=" SELECT * from table2";
$stmt= $mysqli->prepare($ret);

$stmt->execute();
 $res=$stmt->get_result();
 while($row=$res->fetch_object()    )
 {

 ?>                                 
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $row->column1 ?></td>
 <td> <?php echo $row->column3 ?></td>
 <td> <?php echo $row->column3 ?></td>
</tr>

 <?php } ?>                           
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr></tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>




 <h3 class="text-dark mb-4"> <button class="btn btn-info " data-toggle="modal" data- 
  target="#login_itech3">adding column</button></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>



<br>
<?php } ?>
```

I expected to shows me  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v4lL.png) 
but when I run that code it shows me , [one value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIxoz.png)

Comment: If you want two HTML tables, you will need two loops. If you want one table, you can use a JOIN in SQL.

Comment: Yes I want loop, but it loop just one value

Answer (score 0):

You made two mistakes:

1. Used same variable name `$row` for iteration in outer and inner loop
2. Didn't specified `table1_id` in `where` condition in second query
   Try below code, I am, sure It will work

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$ret = " SELECT * from table1
";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($ret);
//$stmt->bind_param('i',$aid);
$stmt->execute(); //ok
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$cnt = 1;
while ($row1 = $res->fetch_object()) {
?>

    <div class="card shadow">
        <div class="card-header py-0">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: none"><?php echo $row1->codes; ?></td>
                    <td style="border: none"><?php echo $row1->titles; ?></td>
                    <td style="border: none">edit</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

            <div class="table-responsive table mt-2" id="dataTable" role="grid" aria- describedby="dataTable_info">
                <table class="table my-0" id="dataTable">
                    <thead>

                        <tr>
                            <th>column 1</th>
                            <th>column 2</th>
                            <th> column 3 </th>


                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php

                        $ret = " SELECT * from table2 where table1_id = ".$row1->id;
                        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($ret);

                        $stmt->execute();
                        $res = $stmt->get_result();
                        while ($row2 = $res->fetch_object()) {

                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row2->column1 ?></td>
                                <td> <?php echo $row2->column3 ?></td>
                                <td> <?php echo $row2->column3 ?></td>
                            </tr>

                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>




            <h3 class="text-dark mb-4"> <button class="btn btn-info " data-toggle="modal" data- target="#login_itech3">adding column</button></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>
<?php } ?>
```